# Resource URL is wrong on page load

Tags: angular, http, weblogic, vaadin

I have two deployments in a weblogic server with context roots: `/java` and `/angular`

The first deployment is a java application which uses vaadin 6 to create its view pages.
The second deployment is an angular2 application.

The java application loads an angular page by using Vaadin's `Embedded` class like so:

```java
    Embedded iframe = new Embedded(null, new ExternalResource("/angular/management/regions"));
    iframe.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
    iframe.setSizeFull();
    addComponent(iframe);
```

The page is **loading correctly in a Development server** but is **failing in a Production server**

**[Problem]**

When the angular page `https://someurl.com/angular/management/regions` is requested, the page fails to load in a Production server because it tries to fetch a resource with a wrong url:

```
https://someurl.com/angular/management/main.b1203599992cbcbea683.js
```

when it should be using: **(no /management in the url)**

```
https://someurl.com/angular/main.b1203599992cbcbea683.js
```

I don't understand why the resource url is correct in a development server and wrong in production when using the exact same .ear file. What type of configurations should I be looking at to fix this issue?

Comment: web contexts can be defined at weblogic.xml, if it is not defined there then will be taken from filename of the war file. Do you have a weblogic. context declared? <wls:context-root>

Comment: @devwebcl Yes, I have <context-root> defined for both modules. They are defined as /java and /angular

Comment: /management URI is seen usually in RESTful management resources. It is a feature introduced in Weblogic 12.x release. Your Dev and Prod are running on same version? 
Can you try disabling RESTful Management Services? Check this: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/domainconfig/EnableRESTfulManagementServices.html

Comment: @NaveenHiremath it's a coindence that it has the same name. I defined the page url as angular/management/regions. If I create another page with angular/management/test/regions it will try to load the resources from angular/management/test/